# Problem involving contraction mappings

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f_1, f_2, \dots f_n : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be $n$ contraction mapings. Prove that there is a unique $(x_1, x_2, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb R^n$ such that $x_1 = f_1(x_n)$ and $x_i = f_i(x_{i-1})$ for $i = 2, 3, \dots, n$.

So far I have proved this holds for $n = 2$, i.e., there is a unique $(x_1, x_2)\in \mathbb R^2$ such that $x_1 = f_1(x_2)$ and $x_2 = f_2(x_1)$. How can I generalize this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Composition of contractions is a contraction. Let $f=f_1\circ f_n \circ f_{n-1}...\circ f_2$. let $x_1$ be  fixed point of this contraction (which exists by Contraction Mapping Theorem). Now define $x_i=f_i(x_{i-1})$ for $2 \leq i \leq n$. Verify that this defines $(x_1,x_2,..,x_n)$ satisfying the required property.